# Size of embedded sdk spotify

Tags: sdk, embedded, spotify

I'm investigating to add Spotify Connect to my hardware audio player having an embedded microcontroller.

What would be the memory size needed to add the Spotify Connect embedded SDK to my firmware?

- In case I do the decompression in my microcontroller.
- In case I don't do the decompression in the microcontroller and just passing the compressed streaming data (e.g. via SPI) to an external hardware decoder.

Comment: Ooh, could be quite a bit. How much have you got? Have you tried goggling for, let's just make a wild guess at this: _spotify connect sdk memory size_ and then looked through the results?

Comment: Hi Barny, thanks for the idea. I've already tried several searches in the search engine but no result showing the answer. After your message, I've searched again using yous words and the top result was my question :)

Comment: For me, the third answer is titled "Memory Usage - Spotify" see here https://support.spotify.com/is/using_spotify/search_play/memory-usage/

Comment: Thank again Barny. Unfortunately this page tells about memory use in iOS or Android devices. I'm looking for the memory use to apply spotify connect into a hardware audio player using a micro controller. So it's the memory use in an embedded system by use of the embedded SDK of spotify.

Comment: The question "what is the memory size of a binary for any microcontroller" doesn't make any sense. The size of the linked library will depend on the specific CPU instruction set and also on the compiler. Thus this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: The microcontroller is an ARM M4. I'm just looking fan an indication; is it 1 kB, 10 kB, 100 kB, 1 MB or more than that?

Comment: Well, I havent signed an NDA, so I have no idea what form the SDK is (C code, java classes, etc), but it likely isn't 1kB or 10kB.  100kB is more in the right magnitude, though you need to include (almost certainly) a network stack (which is probably 100kB in its own) and maybe a database abstraction (also 100kB in its own).   And that isn't including the audio codec (probably 50kB or more per codec, assuming one format) or any sort of UI or RTOS.    So, my guestimate is the 1MB order of magnitude.